# Как настроить File Watcher в PHP storm

Tags: файлы, phpstorm, sass, scss

Не могу ни как сообразить, какую выставить маску макросов, чтоб получить нужный результат.
В проекте есть SCSS категория со своим деревом, и есть точно такае жа папка CSS с той же структурой каталогов. Как мне отстроить параметр компиляции, в нужную папку. Проблема в том, что то что находиться в корне SCSS спокойно ложиться в корень CSS. Но вот те папки что вложены глубже, ни как не устроить их правильно. Дело в том, что папки CSS и SCSS находятся не в корне проекта. Они сами по себе уложены в глубине. То есть вот такой путь: M:/themes/theme01/scss и соответственно M:/themes/theme01/css. То что я редактирую SCSS то нормально ложиться в CSS. Но есть так же глубже папки. К примеру, когда я редактирую SCSS файл, который находиться по адресу M:/themes/theme01/scss/modules/mododule12/css/style.scss он уже не компилируется в M:/themes/theme01/css/modules/mododule12/css/style.css. Он появляется в той же папке что и сам SCSS. Среди макросов, в настройках "наблюдателя" я так и не нашёл нужной переменно. По сути, мне нужно как то указать мой собственный корень, откуда будет расти дерево CSS папки и SCSS (т.е. M:/themes/theme01/). Через макросы нет ничего подобного. Помогите, есть ли какое решение?

Comment: Было дело, хотел настроить аналогично компиляцию из LESS в CSS, но столкнулся с точно такими же проблемами. В итоге перешел на использование gulp, который предоставляет более широкие возможности. У него есть метод [gulp.watch](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb), благодаря которому можно запустить задачу в режиме отслеживания за изменениями файлов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать использовать `$FileDirPathFromParent$`. Скажем, если папка `M:/themes/theme01` соответствует корню проекта, настройки могут выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Arguments: --no-cache --update $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(scss)$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Working directory: $FileDir$

Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(scss)$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(scss)$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```